# How use absolute link in href header

Tags: php, html, path, href, absolute-path

I work on my website but I have a problem with the links in the href.

My CSS and javascript files are in this folder (in the root of my site):

```
assets/stylesheets/file_css.css
```

For now the links of my href looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/stylesheets/media-queries.css">
```

I call it in all my php files with :

```
require_once __DIR__.'/layouts/header.php'
```

**Problem:**

When I want to create a folder to sort my files eg **views** (folder found at the root of my site)

Looks like `views/test.php`

All href don't work, console error :

```
test.php:10 GET http://localhost/mywebsite/views/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css 
test.php:11 GET http://localhost/mywebsite/views/assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 
test.php:12 GET http://localhost/mywebsite/views/assets/stylesheets/custom.css
```

In fact, my CSS aren't in views folder.

I tried many things

```
1 - <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
error => test.php:10 GET http://localhost/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css 

2 - <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo __DIR__ ?>/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
error => test.php:10 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/wamp/www/mywebsite/layouts/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

I thought to put `href="/mywebsite/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"` in the first link, it works locally but not on the server

I really need help, I start having too much PHP file at the root

Thank you

Comment: "~" should resolved your issue e.g "~/mywebsite/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"

Comment: Thank you for your reply but in my server I don't have "mywebsite" so when Ipush it on the server it will not work

Comment: your problem is `require_once __DIR__.'/layouts/header.php'` because the DIR gets your current directory. In your last case is `bla/bla/root/views` and the same goes for `./` shows the current directory

Comment: So How I Can change this ? I use this method because a user recommended me on stackoverflow :(